# type mismatch error in akka dsl route directive

Tags: scala, future, actor, akka-http

I'm setting up a rest controller with akka http. The controller parses the url, extracts variables, then calls a service which sends a message to an actor, which then queries a repository and sends the data as a message. I finally got the actor to receive the message and query the repo (after having to chain a series of futures), but now I have an error in the controller that I can't understand:

```
Error:(58, 41) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => 
scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
path("process" / Segment) { process =>
```

Does this mean I have to include a complete() somewhere else?

I tried making sure that the actor sends a future as the contents of its message, and that the service returns a future to the controller, because I thought this is the only way to avoid null pointers.

These are my dependencies:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http"   % "10.1.8",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor"  % "2.5.22",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.22",
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.1.8"
```

This is the rest controller:

```
val processRoute =
path("process" / Segment) { process =>
  withoutRequestTimeout {
    parameters("userName", "limit") { (twitterUserName, limit) =>
      get {
        val processRequest: ProcessRequest = new ProcessRequest(twitterUserName, process, limit.toInt)
        import JsonSupport._
        process match {

          case "shout" =>
            val serviceResult // add more cases in future or call method dynamically
            = processService.shout(processRequest)
            var listOfTweetTexts: List[String] = List[String]()

            serviceResult onComplete {
              case Success(result) =>
                for (tweet <- result.tweets) listOfTweetTexts ::= tweet;
                complete(listOfTweetTexts)
              case Failure(t) =>
                actorSystem.log.error("An error has occurred: " + t.getMessage)
                complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "Say hello to failure"))

            }
          // complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "Say hello to" + limit))
          case _ => complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "Say hello to" + limit))
        }
        complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "Say hello to" + limit))
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? It is really hard to work out the nesting in this code!

Comment: sorry about that, it's edited now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `onComplete` on a `Future` which returns `Unit`. What you want to do is use the Akka `onComplete` on the `Future`.

So it should be

```
onComplete(serviceResult) {
```

rather than

```
serviceResult onComplete {
```

Comment: Areyou sure Tim? The examples I've seen have a complete being returned to an onComplete within a route : https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onComplete.html

Comment: That is a different `onComplete` provided by Akka Http. You are calling `onComplete` on a `Future`, which definitely returns `Unit`.

Comment: now I have the following error : Error:(53, 41) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
    path("process" / Segment) { process =>